# Bind JSON http response to Angular 6 components

Tags: json, angular, httpclient, angular6, subscribe

I'm getting below JSON response from my HttpClient GET method

```
{
  shortDescription: "3", 
  promotionName: "2", 
  highResolutionImage: "4", 
  lowResolutionImage: "5", 
  promotionOrChallengeCode: "aaa"
}
```

**Promotion.ts**

```
export interface IPromotion
{

    PromotionOrChallengeCode:string;
    PromotionName:string;
    ShortDescription:string;
    HighResolutionImage:string;
    LowResolutionImage:string;
}
```

**In my Component class**

```
promotion:IPromotion;

onSubmit() : void {

    this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:8080/api/search/'+this.pcode )
    .subscribe((response:IPromotion) => 
          { 
            console.log(response);
            this.promotion = response; 
            console.log(this.promotion.PromotionOrChallengeCode);
          });
    }
```

In the Browser console, I'm able to view the JSON response (Output of first console statement).
And the output of second console statement is displayed as "Undefined"

Let me know how to read JSON data and bind to HTML elements

Below are the current Angular versions I'm using:

```
C:\Users\893108>ng -v

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / ? \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 6.1.2
Node: 8.11.3
OS: win32 ia32
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------

rxjs                         6.2.2

typescript                   2.7.2
```

Comment: what does console.log(response) shows?

Comment: Names are case senstive, so `PromotionOrChallengeCode` is not the same as `promotionOrChallengeCode`

Comment: Please, post the exact output request by @Sajeetharan

Comment: JavaScript and JSON are case-sensitive. Don't you see that the JSON properties are not spelt the same way as in your interface? Reagarding binding: this is described in the angular documentation. Have you read it and at least tried something? We won't repeat what the documentation explains. https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data

Comment: Thanks @JB Nizet for your comment.  I'm new to Angular.  I will definitely go through Angular.io documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your inteface as your JSON , you can do with **[`JSON2TS`](http://json2ts.com/)**

```
 export interface RootObject {
        shortDescription: string;
        promotionName: string;
        highResolutionImage: string;
        lowResolutionImage: string;
        promotionOrChallengeCode: string;
}
```

and access it using

```
console.log(this.promotion.promotionOrChallengeCode);
```

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan. You suggestion works fine.  You saved my day:)

Comment: why did you remove the answer?

Comment: Sorry...I thought I can select both answers.  By selecting another, by default it removed yours.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your json interface needs to have same casing as your response from api. Additionally you need to hand the HttpClient in angular the generic signature of your interface.

```
export interface IPromotion
{

    promotionOrChallengeCode: string;
    promotionName: string;
    shortDescription: string;
    highResolutionImage: string;
    lowResolutionImage: string;
}

promotion:IPromotion;

onSubmit() : void {

    this.httpClient.get<IPromotion>('http://localhost:8080/api/search/'+this.pcode )
    .subscribe((response:IPromotion) => 
          { 
            console.log(response);
            this.promotion = response; 
            console.log(this.promotion.promotionOrChallengeCode);
          });
    }
```